# `navigationOptions.headerBackImage` doesn't impact back button in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the next structure of the navigation in the app:

```
StackNavigatior
    TabNavigator
        StackNavigator1
        StackNavigator2
        StackNavigator3
        StackNavigator4
```

When I try to provide the options for `StackNavigator4`

```
  navigationOptions: {
    ...components.navBar,
    headerBackTitle: null,
    headerBackImage: <NavBarBack />,
  },
```

they are ignored - I still get the default react-navigation back button. I have these versions of the related packages:

```
"react-navigation": "3.11.0",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "3.0.2",
```

Before update to 3.x it worked on 2.x

Related GH issue is [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5998)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with using `defaultNavigationOptions` instead of `navigationOptions`